# How to give multiple files in exclude?

Tags: php, terminal, phplint

I am trying to give two folders in `--exclude`. It just gets one.

What I have tried,

```
phplint "C:\laragon\www\customer-service\**\*.php" --exclude="C:\laragon\www\customer-service\vendor,C:\laragon\www\customer-service\node_modules"
```

I have the following files data in phplint.yml. It still searches vendor and node_modules,

```
path: C:\laragon\www\customer-service\**\*.php
jobs: 10
extensions:
  - php
exclude:
  - vendor
  - node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

For the commandline you can add multiple --exclude options, like:

```
phplint "C:\laragon\www\customer-service\**\*.php" --exclude="C:\laragon\www\customer-service\vendor --exclude="C:\laragon\www\customer-service\node_modules"
```

The double qoutes seem optional here.